# Erlang string: How to string join with comma?

Tags: string, erlang

digit list to `csv` for mysql FIND_IN_SET().

```
1> foo("12345").
"1,2,3,4,5"

2> foo("12345", 20).
"21,22,23,24,25".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> join(StringList, Separator) -> String
>
> Types: StringList = [string()] Separator = String = string()
>
> Returns a string with the elements of StringList separated by the
>   string in Separator.

You can try:

```
string:join([[X] || X <- "12345"], ",").
```

Or you can write an function:

```
foo(L, N)->
    string:join( [[X + N] || X<-L], "," ).
```